# How to open browser debugger with custom URL from console.log

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser, console.log

I have an script that adds and/or modifies data for logging to the console, lets call it `logger.js` that can be called like `logger.warn(data)`.

All logs viewed in the console print their origin like `logger.js:123:45` instead of the actual origin. To fix this I am parsing the trace to find the actual origin and logging this to the console as well. When clicked it opens the correct file/location but, in a separate browser tab.

Is it possible to open this URL in the console debugger tool instead? If so how could this be done?